# Import new categories via CSV and assign categories to existing products by SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, import, category-products

I need to be able to import new categories via a CSV file and then in another column have SKUs separated with commas to not only create the new category but also assign it to those products. For example, with the following columns:

- **category name** e.g. category1
- **path** e.g. root/parent_category
- **skus** e.g. sku1,sku2,sku3

The **category name** is the name of the category to add to Magento. The **path** being the location where to store the category and finally put all product **SKUs** in a column separated with commas to associate the newly created category with the products specified in the SKUs column.

Is this doable? Is there an extension that already does this? I have searched only but couldn't find anything. I've looked on here on Stack Exchange for answers but couldn't find anything either.

Any help would be grateful. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: *bump* can anyone help/advice please? That would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my AvS_FastSimpleImport which does that using the category import first and the category product import after that. It doesn't accept CSV files though, but you have to include it into your own module or script.